# Computer frozen after upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade

I logged on to Ubuntu this morning as normal.There was a new upgrade notice. Like I have a couple of times a week for the past three years, I was asked  if I wanted to upgrade. I said yes, the systems downloaded the patch files. After a few minutes, it said I needed to reboot which I did. After rebooting, the system partially froze on startup. I can move the mouse but not am not able to click on any apps. Just a white cursor...

Using Ctrl-Alt-F1, I am able to open a terminal. My question is the following: From the command line, can I undo the upgrade that seemed to have caused the problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to uninstall.  From a Unix & Linux post, the concept is backup before upgrade/updating anything.  There is no real undo action without having a bash script made.  In the future, back everything every time before updating, period.